# How to use an overlapping shader so that it uses layers sort from sprite renderer and its transparent

Tags: unity, 2d, shaders

Im using the shader from
[question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/183097/trying-to-use-an-overlapping-shader-for-2d-sprites-but-sprite-wont-show-its-shap)

, but once I put it in the game, and my character gets close to it, it will be hidden by the shadow of the tree, which is transparent.

Any way to make the shader transparent and/or maybe use the sprite renderer sort layer system

I have been trying to use stencil configurable shader with no luck
Thank you for your help

Not sure what combination of these should work:
[image]

The character is using a normal sprite renderer.

Comment: It looks like you removed the image of your symptoms. Was this intentional?

Comment: Yes I need to replace it

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved the problem giving the character these properties:

[image]

And the tree shades these values:

[image]

As well as making the tree shades the same sorting layer as the character

In order to do this I had to insert the stencil section from here:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/configurable-shaders-open-source-project.518966/

Also I put none in the mask interaction of the character as this is what was hiding the character, not sure if its a bug, but this link also mention it:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/shader-stencil-and-sprite-masks-not-working-together.756041/